# What happens if 3 V of AC power is sent to a 1.5 V motor but the motor is stuck?

Tags: power-supply, motor

I have a demo product box that has a 1.5 V motor, and the power source is an AC/DC adapter that I plug into the wall.

Sometimes the motor is stuck due to another part. The motor is still on (yet stuck) and it gets hot.

What would be the long term damage to the motor if it's stuck for a long time (24 hours, 1 week, 1 month)? Is it a fire hazard?

Specs:
Power source: 3 V, 1 A
Motor: 1.5 V, ≤60 mA，3000 RPM

[image: Motor]

[image]

Comment: It could cause a fire if the battery is powerful enough. Is the battery hot?

Comment: It could range from getting warm to a fire. How much power does it draw. It is possible the motor is impedance protected and will just get hot. I have seen fan and clock motors like that. Can you hold your hand on it, if not it is probably above 135F. Can you post a picture, power source and the rating of the motor.

Comment: Hi all - i edited my question for clarity and added a picture of the motor.  Can you tell from the image of the motor that the motor is an impedance protected?  Last thing I want is a fire to be caused because of this demo box!

Comment: @Charles Give us the datasheet, that'll help a lot more than a picture.

Comment: "≤ 60MA" <-- less than 60 million amps? Also, if you had a cat, a dog and, a tortoise you would have 3 pets (and not 3pets). Engineering is having to be a pedant so I'm sorry if you didn't know that.

Comment: I'm waiting for my product's manufacturer to provide a datasheet.  I measured the temperature of the motor when it's stalled and it's about 65 °C.  I took the reading of the stalled motor after 12 hours and it appears to cap out at that temp.

Comment: Not an answer to the question: the right way IMHO is to have microcontroller identify increased current, and first try to cure situation rotating motor backwards and again forward (if it is possible by mechanic design to clear the jam) and if failed, shut down motor with alarm sound. This solution will NOT cost much, there must be ready to use controller boards for this application.

Comment: Not an answer to the main question, but could be helpful: to make a circuit that automatically resets the motor whenever it gets stuck (if power cycling it works), consider adding 3 things: a limit switch, a MOSFET, and an IC. This IC can be something like a 555 timer or an 8 pin MCU, whichever you like. When the IC doesnt sense a change in the switch (which would be activated by a bump on a gear), it turns off the mosfet, waits a little, then turns it back on again. If an MCU is used, it could try, try, try, then just shut off to protect the motor until the user power cycles the system.

Comment: There may be conceptual design “weakness” - a sidenote and not an answer, ok? Unless for a defect / damaged part, the motor and its reduction gear box should never be “stuck”. If this happens, it means the mechanical power is undersized, or the driven mechanism has points for improvement. But designing something that can withstand one faulty mode and not aggravate is always welcome. I believe this is the OP focus, but surely the **Motor data provided is not correct** - 1.5 V x 60 mA ~= 100 mW and even at 3V it would go as 200 mW. Stall current must be >> 100 mA, probably ~ 1A. Measure that!

Answer (score 4):

In order of increasing effort:

- Add a *PTC fuse* in line with the motor. This will limit the current to a safe value if the motor is blocked. Challenge: once the stall is cleared the current must revert to a low enough value for the fuse to reset.
- Add a *foldback current limiter* to your power supply. That’s a bit more complicated to design, but is very effective. Once the stall is cleared the motor would move as normal.
- If you have a microcontroller running the motor, add a current sensor and use the micro to monitor the current. If it detects a long period of motor stall (that is, high current) it would disable the motor for a time and enter a retry loop.

Comment: As per my 2nd picture I added to my post, I have a very simple circuit and no microcontroller is running the motor.  The PTC fuse option is not desired as there will be no mechanism to revert the current to a low value.  I could add a foldback current limiter to the circuit as it sounds like it resolves my issues.  Will need to consult with an expert for further clarity.

Comment: PTC could work. You can characterize the motor current in its running and stall conditions. Stall needs to be > fuse trip, unblocked < fuse reset. Once you’ve identified some candidate PTCs, it’s very easy to try them out as you just need to wire them in-line with the motor (could even be part of the wiring harness.) and by the way, you have a whole roomful of experts here ;-)

Comment: That said, you could also use a motion encoder (maybe an optical sensor on your gearset) to detect motion, and monitor it with a small micro like an ATTiny. Stalled gearwheel would cause the motor to stop, then retry in a few seconds. This is similar to how brushless DC fans work. You can also monitor the current as I mentioned above.

Comment: As it is, because you have a gear motor I’d be concerned about your gears getting damaged if your mechanism is blocked. You want to limit the motor torque, which the current limiter will do for you. So, do that and monitor motion and do disable-retry upon sensing stall.

Answer (score 4):

A motor is modelled as a speed-dependent voltage source (*back-EMF*), resistance and inductance in series.

First off, I guess this is actually a DC motor fed from DC power source so the inductance is irrelevant.

A freely spinning motor has a back-EMF pretty close to the supply voltage. Current flows proportional to the difference between the back EMF and the supply voltage (divided by the motor's resistance). Since they are close, the current flow is relatively low. This, or somewhere close to this, is often the normal operating condition for a motor.

A stuck motor has zero back-EMF. Therefore the only thing limiting the current flow is the motor's resistance. The current flow is significantly greater, than when the motor runs freely. This amount of current is called the motor's *stall current*, because it's the current it takes when it's stalled, see? If you have the datasheet for the motor, it should tell you what the stall current is. Otherwise, you can measure it if you want to know.

There's nothing inherently wrong with a motor being stalled. However, the greater current generates more heat, and the motor *could* be damaged if it gets too hot. Depending on the power supply it could also damage the power supply by overloading it. *If* the motor is cooled well enough and the power supply is designed for it, the motor should be able to "run" like this all day.

So, how hot is it? If you can comfortably leave your finger resting on the metal part, then it's just warm, not hot, and I wouldn't worry about it. If it's too hot for your finger, then it might be a problem, although it also might not be, since motors can tolerate higher temperatures than fingers. If you have the datasheet, it should tell you what temperature is okay.

Here are some ways to mitigate the problem:

- Sense the temperature of the motor, and turn it off when it's too hot - turn it back on when it's cooled down.
  Some motors have built-in thermal switches, which do this. I'd guess this motor doesn't.
- Sense the current flowing to the motor, and turn it off when it's too high for too long. Turn it back on every now and then to check whether it's still stalled.
- Add a big piece of metal to spread out the heat so it can be transferred to the air more easily.
- Blow air through the motor with a fan.

If you choose to add cooling, transfer heat through metal where possible, not plastic. If you can't attach your cooling system to the back where the metal is already visible, then you might need to make a hole in the plastic part around the motor (not around the gearbox) to attach it.

Also, measure the stall current and make sure your power supply is rated for it.

Comment: I measured the temperature of the metal piece of the motor after 8 hours and it read 65 °C.  I have requested the motor's datasheet from my product's manufacturer so that should provide some clarity.

Comment: I added a 2nd picture in my post which should help explain why some of your suggestions will not work.  The motor is encased in a wooden box (there is a wooden lid that goes over the motor), which is then encased in an acrylic box.  I added a pushbutton switch (N/C) to the circuit so when pushed, the jam dislodges and the demo continues until it gets jammed again.  It's the next customer that pushes the reset button and not the staff.  I cannot have the motor not available for a period of time (ie to cool down).

Comment: @Charles so pressing the reset button usually dislodges the jammed mechanism? I bet you could make it do that automatically, though I'm not sure the best way to make that circuit.

Answer (score 4):

> What's the long term damage to the motor if it's in stuck position for
> a long period of time (24 hours, 1 week, 1 month?)

Impossible to say. It depends on how the motor was designed. But if you were to measure the actual temperature of the outside of the case, that would give a better idea.

And you can measure the copper wire temperature also by contrasting cold resistance with final steady state hot resistance. You would probably need a 4 wire Ohm meter to measure this. If you are interested in pursuing this I can explain in more detail.

The damage, if any, will come from the motor winding overheating. So determining the temperature of the motor winding would be very useful.

> Is there any concern for this to be a fire hazard?

Yes. I don't like "concerns." A "concern" is a possible hazard whose likelihood cannot be estimated very accurately. I like to measure and analyze and test concerns so I can either dismiss them, or employ countermeasures to mitigate the hazard they pose. I don't like to avoid doing something because of a vague concern. I prefer to nail it down.

If the motor is cheap, one idea would be to put it inside of a fireproof container and lock the rotor so it is permanently stuck. Then apply power continuously for, I don't know, maybe 12 hours, and see what happens. If it survives, you could try doing it for several days. If you can also log the temperature, that would be useful, too, to help determine the level of hazard.

Comment: I measured the temperature of the stalled motor after 12 hours and it read 65 °C (quite hot to the touch).  I will try measuring the stalled motor for 1 or 2 days and see if there is any increase in temperature.  Can you elaborate what will happen to the circuit if the motor is damaged (other than the motor not working).

Comment: The insulation on the motor winding could melt, causing an internal short inside the motor. If there is a bearing with grease, the grease could get damaged from the heat. Those are the kinds of things that can happen. Usually there is no electronic circuitry inside the motor. But if there is, it can also get damaged from heat and stop working. I would say 65 C is pretty hot. The winding is probably quite a bit hotter. However, I wouldn't think the 65 C case temperature is likely to ignite anything else outside the motor, at least.

Comment: Did the motor still appear to function normally after 12 hours of stall (and letting it cool down a bit)?

Comment: @Charles 65 degrees is not insanely high. It's hot but not *that* hot. I bet your motor will survive just fine. If you have the datasheet, check what it says about temperature. I assume you measured the metal part and not the plastic part. If the plastic part is 65 degrees then the metal part is hotter.

Comment: @mkeith the motor start right after the circuit was reset and therefore there was no time for the motor to cool down.  The motor operated normally and without issues.